# How to Monitor the Setting of new Properties on Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, object, properties, monitoring

How could I get a callback whenever *new* properties are set on a Javascript Object..?
I.e. I don't know which properties are going to be set, but want a callback for any properties *that* are set.

What I want is

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = "something"; // triggers callback function

function callback(obj,key,val) {
    console.log(key + " was set to " + val + " on ", obj);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It would be much easier to define setters for object attributes, which triggers your callback. `var obj = function() { var item; this.setItem = function(param) { this.item = param; callback(param);} }`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
function onChange(propertyName, newValue){
...
}

var o = {};

Object.defineProperty(o, "propertyName", { 
 get: function() {return pValue; },
 set: function(newValue) { onChange("propertyName",newValue); pValue = newValue;}});
```

But depends on the browser version you need to support.

**Edit: Added snippet on Jsfiddle, works in IE10. http://jsfiddle.net/r2wbR/**

Comment: +1 Now that's cool. I've never read about that method before. I just wish all browsers would support it.

Comment: Just tested in IE9+. Works.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility, it will work in most versions of Chrome, and Firefox. In other browsers, support is offered in later versions.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I want it to work for *any* property, also those of which I do not yet know the name. So setting a listener for a specific property is not going to work, since I don't yet know which properties are going to be set... Still +1 for part of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JavaScript won't let you know when a property is changed. Many times I've wished it would, but since it wouldn't I've had to find a workaround. Instead of setting the property directly, set it via a setter method which triggers the callback function (and possible use a getter method to access the property too) like this:

```
function callback(obj,key,val) {
    console.log(key + " was set to " + val + " on ", obj);
}

var obj = {};
obj.setA=function(value){
    obj.a=value;
    callback(obj,'a',value);// triggers callback function
}
obj.getA=function(){
    return obj.a;
}

obj.setA("something");
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/v8sJt/

EDIT: Another option if you want to completely prevent changing the property without a callback:

```
function callback(obj,key,val) {
    console.log(key + " was set to " + val + " on ", obj);
}

var obj={};
(function(){
   var a=null;
   obj.setA=function(value){
       a=value;
       callback(obj,'a',value);// triggers callback function
   }
   obj.getA=function(){
       return a;
   }
})()

console.log("a is "+obj.getA());// a is null
obj.setA("something"); // Set a to something
console.log("a is now "+obj.getA()); // a is now something
obj.a="something else"; // Set obj.a to something else to show how a is only accessible through setA
console.log("a is still "+obj.getA()); // a is still something
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/wwaL2/

Comment: This will work, but I want to prevent using getters and setters, because that clutters working with objects soo much. Still +1 for thinking along, and special thanks for adding a jsfiddle and not forgetting to fire the callback :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do it is a setter function, you don't need a getter,

```
var obj = {};
setKey(obj, 'a', "something"); // triggers callback function

function setKey(obj, key, val){
    obj[key] = val;
    callback(obj, key, val);
}

function callback(obj, key, val) {
    console.log(key + " was set to " + val + " on ", obj);
}
```

Do it as generic as you can, don't do a different function for all keys

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/nTYN5/3/)

Comment: This will work, but I want to prevent using getters and setters, because that clutters working with objects soo much. Still +1 for thinking along, and special thanks for adding a jsfiddle and not forgetting to fire the callback :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to have setter and getter methods. But according to your previous implementation one could still alter your object properties without using setter and getter. Therfore you should make you senstive variables privat. Here is a brief example:

```
var Person = (function() {

    function Person() {};

    var _name;

    Person.prototype.setName = function(name) {

        _name = name;

    };

    Person.prototype.getName = function() {

        return _name;

    };

    return Person;

})();

var john = new Person();

john.getName();

// => undefined

john.setName("John");
john.getName();

// => "John"

john._name;

// => undefined

john._name = "NOT John";
john.getName();

// => "John"
```

Comment: This will work, but I want to prevent using getters and setters, because that clutters working with objects soo much. Still +1 for thinking along.